# Dynamically compile numba jit

Tags: python, jit, numba

I have many functions for which I seek to support single and multi-threaded execution, which makes me double lines of code, yielding redundant duplication:

```py
@jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
def fn1(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        # [code body]

@jit(nopython=True, cache=True, parallel=True)
def fn1_par(x):
    for i in prange(len(x)):
        # [code body]
```

The code body for both is exactly the same, all that differs is `@jit(parallel=True)` and `range -> prange`. Is there a way for me to express this logic in a *single* function, while keeping the benefits of `cache=True`?

*Note*: workaround with a 'wrapper wrapper' (osvil's answer) fails with `cache=True`; the first call's configs persist (e.g. first function's `parallel=False` will override second's `parallel=True`). Changing the wrapped function's `__name__` doesn't help. Opened [Issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/6845).

Comment: No need to swap out the `prange` for `range`. When called with `parallel=False`, numba will automatically replace `prange` with `range`, allowing you to use the approach outlined in the answer by @osvil

Answer (score 1):

`numba.jit` is just a decorator. You can define the function once and then apply the decorator "manually", multiple times over the same function.

Out of my head, it would look something like:

```
def python_function(x):
   ...

numba_nopython_function = numba.jit(nopython=True)(python_function)
numba_nopython_parallel_function = numba.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)(python_function)
```

Using the function through `numba_nopython_function` will use the plain numba version. Using the `numba_nopython_parallel_function` will use the numba parallel function. You can also access the original python function via `python_function` itself if you fancy. It complies with the DRY principle. Name at your own will, as my verbose-as-hell names are not practical.

I do not know how this would interact with the caching of the functions, though.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon If you use this approach, you can use `prange` when defining the function. This works, because numba will automatically replace `prange` with `range` when called with `parallel=False`

Comment: Right, simple enough, will try. @Bob try non-deterministic computation with and without `prange`, will get different results; this suggests `range -> prange` doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon: You've got things backward. `range` doesn't get automatically converted to `prange`; that would be unsafe. Bob is saying that in non-parallel mode, `prange` is an alias for `range`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ah, my mistake.

Comment: This does not work with `cache=True`; the configuration that wraps `python_function` first will persist, so if e.g. `parallel=False` was first then `parallel=True` is ineffective. (So caching does work).